# How to show vaiable column when calculating mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a data below

```
variety,sulphur,yield
CV1,20.67,1286.0
CV1,19.90,1165.0
CV1,19.73,1176.0
CV1,21.16,1262.0
CV1,21.61,1271.0
CV1,20.90,1221.0
CV1,22.36,1374.0
CV1,21.97,1288.0
CV1,21.90,1285.0
CV2,21.34,1261.0
CV2,21.28,1281.0
CV2,21.90,1302.0
CV2,20.70,1199.0
CV2,22.65,1368.0
CV2,22.16,1340.0
CV2,22.03,1272.0
CV2,20.40,1276.0
CV2,22.47,1329.0
CV3,22.65,1361.0
CV3,21.82,1267.0
CV3,24.41,1380.0
CV3,22.34,1386.0
CV3,24.03,1408.0
CV3,24.38,1380.0
CV3,23.60,1378.0
CV3,23.44,1413.0
CV3,23.51,1400.0
CV4,23.89,1412.0
CV4,24.70,1422.0
CV4,22.80,1381.0
CV4,23.08,1410.0
CV4,25.05,1410.0
CV4,24.09,1381.0
CV4,24.30,1422.0
CV4,25.23,1389.0
CV4,23.14,1403.0
CV5,24.06,1420.0
CV5,26.98,1403.0
CV5,25.71,1400.0
CV5,23.93,1420.0
CV5,25.16,1379.0
CV5,23.79,1393.0
CV5,26.34,1417.0
CV5,24.64,1415.0
CV5,24.77,1383.0
```

Now I'd like to calculate mean by group of variety

```
SELECT * FROM table1.data1;

select avg(yield), variance(yield), stddev(yield) 
from table1.data1 group by variety;
```

but the table does not show the variety column. I want to see how yield is different from varieties (CV1 - CV5), but in this table, I can't.

Could you let me know how to do that?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: By adding variety column into the select list?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because trivial - not useful to others

Comment: @Randy Please close this post. It was a silly question. Please close if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for silly question!! Simply I can select 'variety'

I did not SQL for a long time, so totally forgot the simple code. If someone can, please delete this post if it's silly question (I already got lots of minus reputation).

```
SELECT * FROM table1.data1;
select variety, avg(yield), variance(yield), stddev(yield) 
from table1.data1 group by variety;
```